# Is it canon in DC universe that it is widely known that Superman is an alien?

Tags: dc, superman, arrowverse, canon, supergirl-2015

In the *Supergirl* pilot episode, Supergirl herself argues with a coworker about whether or not aliens exist.

But that wouldn't make sense if Superman is widely known to be an alien in the DC universe.

Comment: The short answer is yes, in nearly every incarnation its widely known that Superman is an alien. Lex Luther, for example, is almost always publicly opposed to Superman out of a hatred for aliens. I don't know how that would apply to the Supergirl continuity.

Comment: I think it's widely known that Superman is an alien but people may not believe that *lots of other* aliens are hiding on Earth. e.g. they think Superman is "unique"

Comment: I haven't seen the pilot so I don't know the specifics of that conversation, but there's also a difference between "handsome aliens who look like humans" and "little green men in flying saucers."  One could easily stand next to a Kryptonian and argue that "aliens don't exist" because you're talking about cow mutilations and light-beam abductions.

Comment: In the supergirl show, it's made pretty clear that the existence of aliens is a secret; As the agent says; "***Our job is keeping people in the dark about alien life on Earth, and nothing says "covert operation" like a flying woman in a red skirt***"

Comment: @TenthJustice - Don't forget G. Gordon Godfrey's blustering over Aliens (and Heroes in general) throughout most of his incarnation in DC stories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not enough is known about the super girl universe yet to know if Superman is regarded as an alien or not. We don't know if Super girl shares universe with Arrow or The Flash or the upcoming Atom series either. Superman if he exists might be considered meta human but in Arrow and the Flash super powered people are just coming into existence. The super girl pilot implies Superman is in active operation at the time.

In most medias, Superman is widely known to be alien as opposed to being a mutant or other type of super powered individual. Superman does not hide it and often shares the info to others about being alien.

Comment: I think the latest official word is that the CW and CBS shows are independent of each other; though the producers apparently have "permission" from the networks to cross over, they aren't planning to. It would be hard to explain how Superman's been around for 24 years and no one in Central City associated him with The Flash...

Comment: Per my earlier comment;  
In the supergirl show, it's made pretty clear that the existence of aliens is a closely guarded secret, known only by a select few; "*Our job is keeping people in the dark about alien life on Earth, and nothing says "covert operation" like a flying woman in a red skirt*"